# add friends logic in database with efficiency

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm looking forward to a logic to store friends list in a database. I'mthinking of adding things in an array with userids

example: user a's array in friends table would contain userid arrays of friends like 1,2,4,6,77,44 etc

I want to know whether this will be an efficient way of doing this. If not, what logic should be ideally implemented for large community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need a separate many-to-many join table. To achieve this, if both the user and their friends reside in the same user table.  The table could look like this:

user_id - id of user the friend lookup is being done for, is foreign key to user_id field in user table
friend_id - id of friend associated with user, also is a foreign key to user_id field in user table

You would have a compound primary key across both fields, ensuring that each user_id to friend_id combination is unique.

This would be sample CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`friend_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `friend_id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

And sample data may look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `friends` (`user_id`, `friend_id`)
VALUES
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 10), (4, 1), (4, 20);
```

Then say you wanted to do a lookup of all the user table data for the friends associated with a particular user (i.e. the logged in user).  You could query that data like this:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN friends ON users.user_id = friends.friend_id 
WHERE friends.user_id = [The ID of current user]
```

Comment: Can you give me the visual structure of the friend_id & user_id table as per your logic to make it a bit clear?

Comment: @user1435686 I have added a table definition and sample data to my answer. You should be able to run these to set up a sample table.  Note here that user 1 would have friends 2, 3, and 4; user 2 would have friends 1 and 10; user 4 would have friends 1 and 20. The id's for friend would reference the same user id column in the user table. So if you ran the query provided with `WHERE friends.user_id = 1` you would get the full user table records for users 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: Thank you. I shall use the you have given. I think there cannot be  a better/efficient way of doing it right considering a big community?

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no!

Don't store multiple values in one db field. It will bring you very much problems.

You could use a stucture like this for instance

```
friends (user_id, user_id)
```

which indicates 2 friends.

Comment: What should I do then?I have a moderate knowledge of databases. I browsed over a few threads, but they had some stuff that I wasn't able to understand well. Can you suggest any reference/source for me to get a hold of the efficient logic?